# Not Able To Add/Edit Category In Magento

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento-1.8

I am having a frustrating issue in Magento Admin Panel. Whenever i try to add a subcategory under default category It only shows "Please Wait" Ajax Loader for a long time and nothing happens. I tried to check by looking into Magento's system and exception logs but nothing is there. It seems to me some server issue which blocking the ajax requests in Magento admin Panel. But everything apart from it is working fine. I added few products and it has been added easily. The problem is with category only.

My Magento Version is 1.8.1.0 and my server(Apache) is on Shared Hosting. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: If Ajax Loader prevents you from accessing action url, you better inspect console error first and please tell us more about that error log.

Comment: No error is showing in JavaScript/firebug console. There is no log created in magento/var/, Even log folder is not there, This is a new website. Where else do i check?

Comment: reindex your site and check in catalog_categoryController file save action and debug

Comment: @faizanbeg I followed the same you as you told here. But no success. Even i delete the saveAction() method from the file just to check. but nothing happened. It seems error is not in category controller or its action, it somewhere when magento send requests to some controller may be ajax or server related. I am not sure.

Comment: check for override category controller

Comment: I did but found nothing suspecting there. One strange thing happened, I asked somebody (who is sitting in US location)to add the subcategory and yes, he is able to do it easily without having any issues. But When i am trying (even with different IPs) nothing happened. Is there any problem with my location or ISP? It's the worst issue i have ever had in magento.

Comment: Well, This issue has been fixed by my server administrator. He found out the router is performing blocks/filtering on some internet requests. So he just bypassed the router blocks through it's own settings.( A Big Relief )